# SolrCloud on HDFS, how to update zookeeper with solrHome on HDFS

Tags: hdfs, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am setting up SolrCloud on HDFS and have followed the steps mentioned in the Solr Guide (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+HDFS).

The SolrHome is a path in HDFS. However, when I try to update Zookeeper configurations (using the solrCloud zkcli.sh), it does not accept an HDFS URI as valid directory for solrHome.

How should the solrHome (on HDFS) be configured with zookeeper?